# Magento 2 Soap webapi error

Tags: magento2, soap

I am creating a soap API in Magento 2, I have created a repositoryInterface for the same, When I fetch all the available WSDL list using below URL. It lists my service as well.

> site_url/soap?wsdl_list=1

It lists my service as well, like below code.

```
<masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1>
<wsdl_endpoint>
http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?wsdl&amp;services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1
</wsdl_endpoint>
</masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1>
```

But when I access the service method via URL, it's set as GET method, it returns errors below.

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" name="MagentoWSDL" targetNamespace="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<types>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<xsd:element name="GenericFault" type="tns:GenericFault"/>
<xsd:complexType name="GenericFaultParameter">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="key" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="value" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfGenericFaultParameter">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>An array of GenericFaultParameter items.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:GenericFaultParameter">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>An item of ArrayOfGenericFaultParameter.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="WrappedError">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="message" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="parameters" type="tns:ArrayOfGenericFaultParameter" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Message parameters.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:natureOfType>array</inf:natureOfType>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfWrappedError">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>An array of WrappedError items.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:WrappedError">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>An item of ArrayOfWrappedError.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="GenericFault">
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="Trace" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Exception calls stack trace.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="Parameters" type="tns:ArrayOfGenericFaultParameter" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Additional exception parameters.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:natureOfType>array</inf:natureOfType>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="WrappedErrors" type="tns:ArrayOfWrappedError" minOccurs="0">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Additional wrapped errors.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:natureOfType>array</inf:natureOfType>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="FrameworkDataImageContentInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Image Content data interface</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="base64EncodedData" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Media data (base64 encoded content)</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="type" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>MIME type</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Image name</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfString">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>An array of string items.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>An item of ArrayOfString.</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="FrameworkDataVideoContentInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Video Content data interface</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="mediaType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>MIME type</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="videoProvider" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Provider</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="videoUrl" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Video URL</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="videoTitle" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Title</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="videoDescription" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Video Description</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="videoMetadata" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Metadata</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="CatalogDataProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryExtensionInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>
ExtensionInterface class for @see \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface
</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="videoContent" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="tns:FrameworkDataVideoContentInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="CatalogDataProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="id" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:int">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Gallery entry ID</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:min/>
<inf:max/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="mediaType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Media type</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="label" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Gallery entry alternative text</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="position" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:int">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Gallery entry position (sort order)</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:min/>
<inf:max/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="disabled" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:boolean">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>If gallery entry is hidden from product page</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:default>false</inf:default>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="types" type="tns:ArrayOfString">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>
Gallery entry image types (thumbnail, image, small_image etc)
</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:natureOfType>array</inf:natureOfType>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="file" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>File path</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="content" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="tns:FrameworkDataImageContentInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>Media gallery content</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="extensionAttributes" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="tns:CatalogDataProductAttributeMediaGalleryEntryExtensionInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>
Existing extension attributes object or create a new one.
</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListRequest" type="tns:MasteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListRequest" nillable="true"/>
<xsd:complexType name="MasteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListRequest">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence/>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:element name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListResponse" type="tns:MasteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListResponse"/>
<xsd:complexType name="MasteringSampleModuleDataItemInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
<inf:callInfo>
<inf:callName>masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetList</inf:callName>
<inf:returned>Always</inf:returned>
</inf:callInfo>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="description" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" type="xsd:string">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:maxLength/>
<inf:callInfo>
<inf:callName>masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetList</inf:callName>
<inf:returned>Conditionally</inf:returned>
</inf:callInfo>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ArrayOfMasteringSampleModuleDataItemInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>
An array of MasteringSampleModuleDataItemInterface items.
</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="tns:MasteringSampleModuleDataItemInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>
An item of ArrayOfMasteringSampleModuleDataItemInterface.
</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:callInfo>
<inf:callName>masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetList</inf:callName>
<inf:returned>Conditionally</inf:returned>
</inf:callInfo>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="MasteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListResponse">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation>
Response container for the masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetList call.
</xsd:documentation>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:sequence>
<xsd:element name="result" type="tns:ArrayOfMasteringSampleModuleDataItemInterface">
<xsd:annotation>
<xsd:documentation/>
<xsd:appinfo xmlns:inf="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1">
<inf:natureOfType>array</inf:natureOfType>
<inf:callInfo>
<inf:callName>masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetList</inf:callName>
<inf:returned>Always</inf:returned>
</inf:callInfo>
</xsd:appinfo>
</xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="GenericFault">
<part name="messageParameters" element="tns:GenericFault"/>
</message>
<portType name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1PortType">
<operation name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetList">
<input message="tns:masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListRequest"/>
<output message="tns:masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListResponse"/>
<fault name="GenericFault" message="tns:GenericFault"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1Binding" type="tns:masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1PortType">
<soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetList">
<soap12:operation soapAction="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetList"/>
<input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="GenericFault"/>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1Service">
<port name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1Port" binding="tns:masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1Binding">
<soap12:address location="http://www.magentolocal.com/soap/default?services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1"/>
</port>
</service>
<message name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListRequest">
<part name="messageParameters" element="tns:masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListRequest"/>
</message>
<message name="masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListResponse">
<part name="messageParameters" element="tns:masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetListResponse"/>
</message>
</definitions>
```

I tried using php SoapClient as well, But retuns empty set in response. Below is code.

```
<?php

class M2SoapTest {

    public $wsdl_url;
    public $soapClient;
    public $context;
    public $shopUsername;
    public $shopPassword;
    public $session;

    /**
     * Add a single condition, or an array of conditions to the WHERE clause of the query.
     * 
     * @param   mixed   $conditions  A string or array of where conditions.
     * @return  JDatabaseQuery  Returns this object to allow chaining.
     * @since   1.0
     */
    public function __construct() {

        //List of availble services
//        $this->wsdl_url = 'http://www.magentolocal.com/soap?wsdl_list=1';
        //Local WSDL
        $this->wsdl_url = 'http://www.magentolocal.com/soap?wsdl&services=masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1';
//        $this->shopUsername = 'featuredproduct';
//        $this->shopPassword = 'FeaturedProduct';
        $this->context = stream_context_create();
        $this->soapClient = new \SoapClient(
                $this->wsdl_url, [
//            'version' => SOAP_1_2,
            'context' => $this->context,
            'trace' => true,
            'exceptions' => true,
            'connection_timeout' => 500000,
            'keep_alive' => false,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_BOTH
                ]
        );

        //Intiial Authentication on initialization of class
//        $this->authenticate();
    }

    /**
     * Add a single condition, or an array of conditions to the WHERE clause of the query.
     * 
     * @param   mixed   $conditions  A string or array of where conditions.
     * @return  JDatabaseQuery  Returns this object to allow chaining.
     * @since   1.0
     */
    public function authenticate() {
        try {
            //Authenticate with shop Services
            $this->session = $this->soapClient->login($this->shopUsername, $this->shopPassword);
            return true;
        } catch (\SoapFault $e) {

            die('issue in login');
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            echo "</pre>";
            die();
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     *  Testing 
     */
    public function testApi() {
        try {
//            $response = $this->soapClient->__getFunctions();
            $response = $this->soapClient->masteringSampleModuleItemRepositoryV1GetList([]);
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($response);
            echo "</pre>";
            die();
        } catch (\SoapFault $e) {

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($e->getMessage());
            echo "</pre>";
            die();
        }
    }

}

$obj = new M2SoapTest();
$obj->testApi();
```

Below is response when execute this file.

```
<pre>stdClass Object
(
    [result] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

)
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks